# Installer stuck at "Configuring target system"

Tags: installation, windows, ubiquity

It's stuck at "Configuring target system"
It's still stuck as of now (I launched the installer from Ubuntu after clicking "try Ubuntu")
How can i solve this?
Should i stop it?
And will it hurt my system?

P.S:I clicked install alongside windows.

Comment: Just cancel and start over, you won't hurt anything.

Comment: In start menu[Try ubuntu/ install ubuntu/ etc]  press F6 then select nomodeset. press ESC. Now select install ubuntu.

Comment: @shantanu: post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

After boot  from liveCD, In start menu[Try ubuntu/ install ubuntu/ etc]
press F6 then select nomodeset.
press ESC.
Now select install ubuntu.